# Redmine Configuration file in Synology Docker

Tags: docker, redmine, synology

I have a Synology server with Redmine installed through Docker on it.

I just want to write down my SMTP configuration inside the configuration.yml. I did it with success on another installation (Ubuntu - Bitnami)

- I understood I should use the Redmine's Container's bash.
- In that bash, I can "vi config/configuration.yml" and add my SMTP config. of course, I write the file on exit.
- but when I restart the container (to restart Redmine) the configuration file is overwritten... so my SMTP configuration is lost.

Any Idea ?

(and please don't ask why I'm always changing the way I install things... I not responsible, I'm just passing after other people at work)

Answer (score 1):

redmine 3.4.13. add environment variables in docker

```
SMTP_PASS
SMTP_USER
SMTP_AUTHENTICATION
SMTP_DOMAIN
SMTP_PORT
SMTP_HOST
SMTP_METHOD
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to change SMTP parameters is to go into the Docker container parameters. There is a list of variables where you have to add some like "SMTP_HOST".